# Calculus proof - derivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have a function $f(x):[a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable. I know that $f(a)=f'_+(a)=0$ and that $\forall x>a, f(x)>0$. I want to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= \infty$. I was suggested to look at the improper integral of $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ which is $ln(f(x))$ but I did not learn about improper integrals yet. What I have learned by now is derivatives, mean value theorems (all the versions, including the integral mean value theorem) and integrals (not improper ones). If you have a proof using these tools only it would be wonderful! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

You can use MVT to get

for $ x>a$,

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(c_x)=(x-a)f'(c_x)$$

with $a<c_x<x$.